# Spring Boot cant find index.html

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Hi i have multi maven spring boot project. Ui(react js) is served from different jar. i am able to run UI when i run npm start, but when i deploy spring boot jar and UI jar into tomcat server i am not able to load index.hmtl. Any help appreciated. I added a contoller to redirect to index page when server starts up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to place the static files under `src/main/resouces/static/` directory. I don't think you need to access index.html via Controller. Have a look at Spring boot docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, sorry to mention my frontend code is in different jar

Comment: What is the structure of the jar in which your front-end code (static files) exist?

Comment: You can always tweak the build of your front-end project so that all static files go into target\classes\static during the maven build process. And when you add the front-end jar as a dependency on your spring-boot app, the index.html should just be located fine. @Kumaresh Babu has pointed you to the right docs.